# Toggle disable button in Razor view ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to toggle between enabling or disabling an html button from a Razor view based on an if statement. This disables the button regardless of the value of the if statement.

```
@{
    disabled = "";
    if (Model.User.PublicId == ViewBag.SiteUser.PublicId)
    {
        followClass += " you";
        followText = "You";
        disabled = "disabled";
    }
}

<button class="@followClass" disabled="@(disabled)">@(followText)</button>
```

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of all of those parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix, just remove disabled="" from the button definition.

```
<button class="@followClass" @disabled >@followText</button>
```

Comment: Disabled is a boolean attribute - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input - the presence of the attribute indicates that the control is disabled - "disabled" by itself is the same as disabled="disabled". As you have discovered removing the attribute will enable the control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the disabled in the button definition you can do the following:

```html
<button @if (@Model.DisableButtonModel) {  @("disabled='1'") }>My Button</button>
```